# What is the SLA from submitting web 2 lead/case to creation of a lead/case in salesforce?

Tags: web2lead, web2case

I couldn't find an answer to this question anywhere, I know it usually happens immediately but would be great to know if there is any SLA or logic on how much time it takes to the lead or case be created in salesforce.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You won't find any documentation about an SLA, because there is no SLA. The amount of time it takes depends on the number of records in the queue before that record. There's no guarantee of how long it will take to appear. If you wanted a better guarantee, consider using an API instead.

For what it's worth, I've seen it take up to about five minutes in some rare cases, and there was once an incident, if I recall correctly, where the queue was down indefinitely because of some problem, but no records were lost and eventually everything was caught up. This was probably 9 years ago or so.

The queue will become backed up when there are performance issues and/or maintenance (because the databases are literally offline). The web to lead and web to case services remain up, and still capture data during maintenance, and those records are caught up in a first-time, first-serve order until the queue is empty again once the system exits maintenance mode. Therefore, you can expect reasonable delays right after a release weekend.

Generally, after a maintenance window, the queue will be backed up for about the same length of time (or less) as the actual window. If maintenance takes 10 hours, you would expect the system to catch up within 10 hours of coming back online.

Comment: @InbalJerby The only guarantee is that no leads or cases are ever lost. If there's validation errors, or limits exceeded, admins still get emails about those records.